# seturlstrategy- page reload not working :Flutter web 2.0

Tags: flutter-web, flutter2.0

I have used `setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());` to remove # from the url, but since then my pages stopped reloading after I deploy my project on web, it shows 404 page not found. but works perfectly on localhost.
if I remove `setUrlStrategy(PathUrlStrategy());` and build again to deploy on web it works. but that # shows on url.
Can anyone help?

p.s: I used my project on non root location, and have already added my project name in index file, my project works if I open first page to next file, but not directly when open next file from url.

Answer (score 3):

ok i found the problem, it was because i didn't use `.htaccess` file.

here is htaccess code if anyone get same problem.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myproject/index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

put this file where your index file is.

Comment: where do you have this htaccess file?

Comment: You have to create the .htaccess file manually inside this folder ->  build/web @Iftekhar

Comment: Works for Hostgator till date, Thanks!